# Jhipster custom blueprint: How define a custom command line parameter (option)

Tags: jhipster

I'm building a custom blueprint for my organization's projects. Apparently, It's everything working fine.

I need to ask for a specific information to the blueprint user. So I've done in the PROMPTING priority, it works.
However, I want the user to be able to pass this info via command line parameter. So I thought that creating a custom parameter (option) would be a good idea, so I've done something like this:

```js
export default class extends GeneratorBaseEntities {
    constructor(args, opts, features) {
        super(args, opts, { taskPrefix: PRIORITY_PREFIX, ...features });

        this.option('parentProject', {
            desc: 'Inform the parent project',
            type: String,
        });
        ...
```

Then I've executed the command line:

```bash
jhipster jdl --blueprints my-java-blueprint --parentProject MyParentProject --skip-install ~/myjdl.jdl
```

Then, I've got the following error:

```
INFO! No custom sharedOptions found within blueprint: generator-jhipster-my-java-blueprint at /home/.nvm/versions/node/v16.18.0/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster-my-java-blueprint
(node:23361) [DEP0148] DeprecationWarning: Use of deprecated folder mapping "./lib/util/" in the "exports" field module resolution of the package at /home/.nvm/versions/node/v16.18.0/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-environment/package.json.
Update this package.json to use a subpath pattern like "./lib/util/*".
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
error: unknown option '--parentProject'
```

How could I create a new command line parameter for my custom blueprint?

I've also tried the following way in the constructor but the result is the same:

```js
 this.jhipsterOptions('parentProject', {
    desc: 'Sigla do módulo SAD do qual os microsserviços farão parte',
    type: String,
 });
```

Comment: So you have open a github issue https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/20444 which is more appropriate. I propose you close this question to avoid mess of cross posting

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved when I've created a new generator 'app', extending of AppGenerator class.
There, I've declared my option and it was recognized throughout the blueprint

```js
export default class extends AppGenerator {
    constructor(args, opts, features) {
        super(args, opts, { taskPrefix: PRIORITY_PREFIX, ...features });

        this.option('parent-project', {
            desc: 'Inform the parent project',
            type: String,
        });
        ...
```